# Spring Jms receive batch message

Tags: amazon-sqs, spring-jms

I can simply use this code to receive messages from queue

```
List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(queueUrl).getMessages();
```

It will get 10 messages at max from the queue as per amazon documentation

Lets say i have 10k messages and i want 800 TPS for consumption. So i tried Spring Jms implemention of jms listener, defined a JMS listener and defined a concurrency of "5-100".

```
@JmsListener
public void getMessage(String message) {
//process it
}
```

i can define something like this

```
  @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() throws Throwable {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());

        factory.setConcurrency("5-100");
        return factory;
    }
```

I am still not able to reach that 800 TPS with it. Is there any way to fetch 10 message per thread or something, Instead of getting one message , can we do 10 messages which ultimately increases the throughput? 
If you have some better suggestions, please do ?

How one optimize when the producer is producing more and consumer is consuming less?

How do you tune your jms listener? 
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Estimate SQS processing time and load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493547/estimate-sqs-processing-time-and-load) - note that the main point is about how to achieve high TPS throughput

Comment: No. It's not the same. I want to handle 800 Tps. Currently. I can handle 100 Tps at max.

Comment: can you unclose it? @Krease